# How can I stop MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE duplicating pictures

Tags: android, android-camera, android-gallery

I am using the following code to take a picture:

```
private static final int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 1;

final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(tFile));
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
```

This code works fine however I am getting a copy of every picture I take automatically appearing in the "Camera Shots" gallery as well as where I want the picture to go.

How do I stop it automatically copying my picture?

The file name is not even the same as the one I specified so it is not like I can delete it easily.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I found an example of someone who added a listener so when they take a picture it notifies them that an image has been placed in the gallery and this can then be removed but I would much rather stop the duplicate image in the first place. Any ideas as I am really stuck on this one?

Comment: Hi Lee, have you found a answer for this issue ? Because I got the same problem. Thanks

Comment: No I still haven't figured out how to fix this. I am currently trying to find some code that lets me get the file name of the latest picture added to the gallery so I can delete it. If I can't stop it duplicating images at least if I can delete the duplicates it is the next best thing.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a answer.

Following function delete the last photo saved to media storage.

```
public void deleteLastCapturedImage() {
    String[] projection = { 
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.SIZE,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA, 
            BaseColumns._ID
    };

    Cursor c = null;
    Uri u = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    try {
        if (u != null) {
            c = managedQuery(u, projection, null, null, null);
        }
        if ((c != null) && (c.moveToLast())) {

            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            int i = cr.delete(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, BaseColumns._ID + "=" + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID)), null);

            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Number of column deleted : " + i);

        }
    } finally {
        if (c != null) {
            c.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Please call above function within onActivityResult.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go when I get a chance and see how I get on!

Comment: U r just deleting Users image on those handset who don't have this behavior just check your code again

Comment: I am deleting the photo just after taking. This is just a part of the coding.